# enum variable has to be initialized in dart >>>>>>>>>>> Can you please tell me how to declare this variable

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

How can I declare the selectedGender variable? I'm having an initialize error.
The variable is inside a StatefullWidget.

```
enum Gendertype {male, female}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Gendertype selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      child: Expanded(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              selectedGender=  Gendertype.male;
            });
          },
          child: ReusedCard(
            labledcolor: selectedGender==Gendertype.male?
            inactivekcardcolor:activekcardcolor,
            childCard: CardIcon(genderIcon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
            labletype: "Male",
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your post (format code as code) and add some details. And. please read: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

According to the null safety rules, you have these options:

- Declare `selectedGender`as a nullable variable:

```dart
Gendertype? selectedGender;
```

- Define a first value to the variable:

```dart
Gendertype selectedGender = Gendertype.male
```